# Counting word frequency using LinkedLists

Tags: java

I am new here and I am learning to code. I am doing an exercise in which I need to find the frequency of words in a given string and put them in a LinkedList. I feel as though I am fairly close but no cigar. Any help would be appreciated.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    String test = "Informatics is the future It is a bridge to all things useful 
    Informatics harnesses the power and possibility of digital technology to 
    transform data and information into knowledge that people use every day This 
    strong focus on the human use of computing helps people to interact with 
    technology in the best and most efficient way possible Computer scientist 
    believe informatics is the human part of the IT equation making computer 
    software and hardware relatable accessible and enjoyable to use";

    String lower = test.toLowerCase();
    String[] split = lower.split(" ");
    LinkedList<String> words = new LinkedList<>(Arrays.asList(split));
    String strings = new String();
    LinkedList<Integer> count = new LinkedList<>();

        for(int j = 0; j<split.length; j++)
        {

        for (int i = 0; i < test.length(); i++)
        {
            if (words.contains(test))
            {
                int index = words.indexOf(test);
                count.set(index, count.get(index) + 1);
            }
            else
                {
                 words.add(strings);
                 count.add(1);
           }
      }
  }

    for (int i = 0; i < words.size(); i++)
    {
        System.out.println(strings + " : " + count.get(i));


    }
}
```

Comment: P{lease format (indent) your code correctly.  The task you are trying to accomplish requires a `Map<String,Integer>` data structure, not a `List`.

Comment: @JimGarrison, `List` can be used also, but with a `custom object (String,Int)`

Answer (score 0):

The major flaw in this code is that the input string `test` is converted to lower case, then split to words into a list, and after that *many times* it verifies if the list of *words in lower case* contains the entire input string `test`.  Of course, this condtion is never true.

The correct logic should be to iterate through the list of words, increase counter if a duplicate is found and remove the duplicate entry (thus reducing `words` size).

This can be done using [`ListIterator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ListIterator.html) which can be set to specific position in the list using method [`List::listIterator(int index)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#listIterator-int-):

```java
String test = "Informatics is the future It is a bridge to all things useful Informatics harnesses "
    + "the power and possibility of digital technology to transform data and information into knowledge "
    + "that people use every day This  strong focus on the human use of computing helps people to interact "
    + "with technology in the best and most efficient way possible Computer scientist believe informatics "
    + "is the human part of the IT equation making computer  software and hardware relatable accessible "
    + "and enjoyable to use";

String lower = test.toLowerCase();
String[] split = lower.split("\\s+"); // use regex \s+ to discard multiple spaces
LinkedList<String> words = new LinkedList<>(Arrays.asList(split));
LinkedList<Integer> counts = new LinkedList<>();

System.out.println("Initial words count:" + words.size());
for (int currIndex = 0; currIndex < words.size(); currIndex++) {
    ListIterator<String> it = words.listIterator(currIndex);
    String word = it.next(); // keep current word
    int wordCount = 1;

    while (it.hasNext()) {
        if (word.equals(it.next())) {
            wordCount++;
            it.remove(); // delete duplicate if found
        }
    }

    counts.addLast(wordCount);
    System.out.printf("%-11s: count=%2d, index=%2d, words=%2d%n", 
            word, wordCount, currIndex, words.size()
    );
}
```

Output (part):

```
Initial words count:79
informatics: count= 3, index= 1, words=77
is         : count= 3, index= 2, words=75
the        : count= 6, index= 3, words=70
future     : count= 1, index= 4, words=70
it         : count= 2, index= 5, words=69
a          : count= 1, index= 6, words=69
bridge     : count= 1, index= 7, words=69
to         : count= 4, index= 8, words=66
all        : count= 1, index= 9, words=66
things     : count= 1, index=10, words=66
useful     : count= 1, index=11, words=66
harnesses  : count= 1, index=12, words=66
power      : count= 1, index=13, words=66
and        : count= 5, index=14, words=62
....
computer   : count= 2, index=44, words=54
scientist  : count= 1, index=45, words=54
believe    : count= 1, index=46, words=54
part       : count= 1, index=47, words=54
equation   : count= 1, index=48, words=54
making     : count= 1, index=49, words=54
software   : count= 1, index=50, words=54
hardware   : count= 1, index=51, words=54
relatable  : count= 1, index=52, words=54
accessible : count= 1, index=53, words=54
enjoyable  : count= 1, index=54, words=54
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a custom List

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class WordCount {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String test = "Informatics is the future It is a bridge to all things useful Informatics harnesses "
    + "the power and possibility of digital technology to transform data and information into knowledge "
    + "that people use every day This  strong focus on the human use of computing helps people to interact "
    + "with technology in the best and most efficient way possible Computer scientist believe informatics "
    + "is the human part of the IT equation making computer  software and hardware relatable accessible "
    + "and enjoyable to use";
    String lower = test.toLowerCase();
    String[] split = lower.split("\\s+");
    CustomList<Object> cList = new CustomList<Object>();
    for (int i = 0; i < split.length; i++) {
        cList.addWord(split[i]);
    }
    cList.forEach(System.out::println);
    }
    }

class CustomList<Words> extends ArrayList<Object> {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

public void addWord(String name) {
    for (int i = 0; i < this.size(); i++) {
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        Words word = (Words) this.get(i);
        if (word.name.equals(name)) {
            word.count = ++word.count;
            return;
        }
    }
    this.add(new Words(name, 1));
}

class Words {
    int count;
    String name;

    Words(String name, int count) {
        this.name = name;
        this.count = count;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return name + ":" + count;
    }
}
}
```

Output

```
informatics:3
is:3
the:6
future:1
it:2
a:1
bridge:1
...
```